# Termination condition of Redis sscan (or scan) operation

Tags: redis

I'm using Redis with set structure via SADD, SREM to insert and delete respectively.
At some point in time, I need to iterate all elements in the set and process them and lastly remove each element from the set. To iterate all elements, I used [SSCAN](https://redis.io/commands/scan). In the documentation, they said as follows,

*The commands are also allowed to return zero elements, and the client should not consider the iteration complete as long as the returned cursor is not zero*.

To iterate all elements in the set, I started the cursor from zero. And then, I processed each element returned from SSCAN and remove each element from the set by using SREM operation. I used the cursor returned from previous result of SSCAN operation for the next iteration. This process continues until both the cursor returned from SSAN is zero and there are no elements in the returned array. During the iteration no new element is added into the set.
However, After finishing the process, there exist elements left in the set.
In my expectation, the set should be empty. What's the problem?
Should I check whether there are elements in the set? For example, by using SCARD?

Here is the operation I did,

```
SADD key element
SADD key element
..
..

result = SSCAN key 0 Count 100
while elements and next_cursor != 0:
  for e in elements
    process e
    SREM key
  SSCAN key next_cursor Count 100

// process the last result returned with zero value cursor
for e in elements
  process e
  SREM key
```

Answer (score 1):

> This process continues until both the cursor returned from SSAN is zero and there are no elements in the returned array

This is incorrect. You should only check if the cursor returned is 0.

```
cursor = 0
while true:
    cursor = SSCAN key cursor count 100
    process_elements
    if cursor == 0:
        break
```